# Changing tickmark size on logarithmic axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the length and width parameters of `ax.tick_params()` the size of the tickmarks on the axes can be changed. However, if I create a plot on the logarithmic scale, it leaves the tickmarks indicating the logarithmic scale unchanged. In the example below for instance, the tickmarks of 2,3,4,...,20,30,... remain the same size. Is there a way that the size of these tickmarks can also be changed?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.logspace(0,2,1000)
y = np.exp(x)

plt.loglog(x,y)
plt.tick_params(length = 5, width = 3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The magic word here is [`which`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) to distinguish between major and minor ticks. The default is `major`, hence your observation. I am sure there is a duplicate somewhere but I am too lazy to look for it.

Comment: Ah I see. It appears that if I set which = 'minor', the intermediate tick marks will be affected, and which='both', both will be affected. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Most of matplotlib's functionality is well-documented, either in examples/tutorials or, as linked, in the documentation. As we can see, there is also the useful keyword `axis`.